# Cucumber; Selenium WebDriver - how to use Google Chrome as the testing browser instead of Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, browser, selenium, cucumber

For a Cucumber scenario on my Rails 3.1 app, I used the @javascript tag, so Selenium is activated.
I get the following error:

```
Could not find Firefox binary (os=macosx). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path= (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

If possible, I'd like to use Google Chrome as the browser - not Firefox (which I haven't installed). Is this possible? What could be done?

In fact, shouldn't Cucumber/Selenium detect a browser and use it?

====EDIT====

After adding

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

...to features/support/env.rb,
I now get this error:

```
Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:45:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'
  features/update_memories.feature:11:in `Given I am on the home page'
```

I've downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/detail?name=chromedriver_mac_14.0.836.0.zip&can=2&q=), and I've tried putting the chromedriver executable in /usr/bin, but I still get the above error.

====EDIT 2====

After going one step further and running "sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver" as suggested below, I now get a new error after running cucumber:

```
@javascript
  Scenario: navigate to memory update page from home page              # features/update_memories.feature:11
    Given I am on the home page                                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
      unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:57870 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:45:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'
      features/update_memories.feature:12:in `Given I am on the home page'
    When I activate the edit memory switch for the memory "I played"   # features/step_definitions/memories/memory_steps.rb:5
    Then I should be on the edit memory page for the memory "I played" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:187
      PGError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
      : ROLLBACK (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Help appreciated! Getting closer...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For capybara, add this to *env.rb*

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

Download the [Chrome driver executable](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list) and copy it in you path, e.g. */usr/bin/* and make it executable

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: Okay, I got one step further with the chmod command you specified (thanks!), but I now get a new error. I'm updating my question right now.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to install chromedriver with Homebrew, but needed to add /usr/local/bin to my Textmate PATH in Preferences -> Advanced -> Shell Variables

Comment: For me this solution was successfull only when I placed driver into /usr/bin. Placing it into /usr/local/bin (also included in PATH) did not the trick.

Comment: Hey everyone. Don't download chromedriver2. It doesn't work. I don't think the rails selenium gem is set up for it. Remove this comment if anything has changed.

Comment: link to Chrome drive executables has changed to http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: I just added this to `spec_helper.rb` anywhere and did not need to run the `sudo` command, in case it's helpful to anyone else. Also after you download the Chrome driver, you have to unzip before putting it in your /usr/bin/ folder

Comment: I downloaded it from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html     and when I execute `sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver`, I got `Operation not permitted` error.

Comment: I finally succeeded with `sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: THANK YOOOOOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU. P.S, in rails with rspec, i just had to put this in spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 3):

Today the easiest way to get the chromedriver executable seem to be installing the chromedriver-helper gem. Please see https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper for details.

Besides installing the gem you'll have to configure your environment the same way as already mentioned in several other answers:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using capybara try this

`Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|`
  `Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)`
`end`

See [capybara docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for additional details (especially take a look into Configuring and adding drivers section)

Comment: I followed what you suggested, but I get a new error (see updated question)... any chance you could help out and update your answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver' # specify the path of chromedriver
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the setting "*chrome" to "*googlechrome" in the class setUp function.

Comment: No. Selenium itself has the confusing *chrome vs *googlechrome options, but in Capybara the options are the less crazy :firefox vs :chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the path of chrome drivers in your PATH variable if you are on a linux distro with bash.

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Download the Chrome driver executable and copy it in you path, e.g. /usr/bin/ and make it executable

$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver

this worked for me