# unable to connect to chromedriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver

I use capybara & selenium to test my rails project. When I execute the test script, it has errors likes this:

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
   Could not find Firefox binary (os=macosx). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=
```

I googled [how to use Google Chrome as the testing browser instead of Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821659/cucumber-selenium-webdriver-how-to-use-google-chrome-as-the-testing-browser-i)

but it causes other errors like:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
   unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515
```

Comment: What version of Firefox and Chrome do you have? Where exactly are they installed to?

Comment: i installed firefox through brew, the version of firefox is "firefox: 21.0"

Comment: Can you post your gemfile as well as your cucumber env file?

Answer (score 58):

I had the exact same issue. What worked for me was using the "webdrivers" gem. Part of my gemfile looks like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

Comment: The error first came up after updating `selenium-webdriver 3.8.0`
to `3.9.0`. Adding the `chromedriver-helper` gem solved the problem

Comment: NOTICE: chromedriver-helper is deprecated as of 2019-03-31
Please update to use the 'webdrivers' gem instead.
See https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper

Answer (score 11):

On Mac OS

It works fine with watir-webdriver and Safari

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :safari
```

If you'd like to use Chrome, make sure that it is installed, plus you need to install mac os developer tools with

```
xcode-select --install
```

and also install chromedriver with brew

```
brew install chromedriver
```

On Linux

I had the same error on my staging Ubuntu 12.04 server and the problem was I didn't install chrome itself like this (with superuser permissions):

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
apt-get update
apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Install chromedriver(use proper path for your system and version):

```
wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.7/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
cp chromedriver /usr/local/bin
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

After that I would recommend you to use watir-webdriver in headless mode

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto 'http://google.com'

...

browser.close
headless.destroy
```

Good luck!

Comment: How is this related to running tests in capybara? watir-webdriver is a different framework entirely...

Answer (score 10):

Running on Ubuntu 12.10, I also had the error message:

```
unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515
```

Wasn't working even after I downloaded it and installed it correctly.  I even tried using the chromedriver-helper gem.  So I ran chromedriver manually (/usr/bin/chromedriver) and found out 2 things:

1) I had a missing package dependency on libnss3 which was fixed using `sudo apt-get install libnss3`

2) Version 2.9 of chromedriver (latest as of Feb 2014) requires chrome > version 31, and I had v25, which was fixed using `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable`

Answer (score 2):

mac osx 10.9.4, jruby 1.7.6, selenium-webdriver 2.42.0, brew install chromedriver -> installed 2.10

```
got unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

found this-> https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6574#c3

We have patched webdriver/chrome/service.rb to contain

```
@process.io.stdout = Tempfile.new("chromdriver-output")
before @process.start
```

which SOLVED the issue - crikey!

Answer (score 2):

mac osx 10.10 with jruby 1.7.12

```
unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515
```

found this-> https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6574#c3

```
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    module Chrome
      class Service
        alias_method :old_start, :start
        def start
          @process.io.stdout = Tempfile.new("chromdriver-output")
          old_start
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just changed it to `@process.io.stderr = ` to get a helpful error message.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X? Using Brew? Missed the instructions?

```
$>> brew info chromedriver

chromedriver: stable 2.20
...
==> Caveats
To have launchd start chromedriver at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/chromedriver/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load chromedriver now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.chromedriver.plist
```

Follow them :) worked for me. Also helps to open chrome, it might need updating.

Comment: in case it helps anyone else, the opposite was true for me - i had to NOT have it running (i had to find the process and kill it), and i had to delete some other binaries/shims i found with `which chromedriver` until it was just the one installed with brew (mine was `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`) and then run my tests again and this time they worked!

Answer (score 1):

i had some issue when configurate circle ci

- add to Gemfile interface for Xvfb

`gem 'headless', '~> 2.3.1'`

- add to spec/rails_spec.rb

`if ENV['HEADLESS'] == 'on'
  require 'headless'
  headless = Headless.new
  headless.start
end`

so run your rspec by
`HEADLESS=on bundle exec rspec`

Example of the working configuration where this problem is solved:

### [circle.yml](https://gist.github.com/Mifrill/bb1cfc81884620148e3e2fe476fe7859)

- reinstall Chrome
- install ChromeDriver
- install Selenium

Here's an excellent manual how to do it: 
https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5

Comment: As for firefox error - just need to install firefox: `sudo apt-get install firefox`

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu-14-04-x64

**unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515**

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.33.506092

$ which chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

---

```
 wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/chromedriver_linux64.zip

    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip

    chmod +x chromedriver

    sudo mv -f chromedriver /usr/local/share/chromedriver

    sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

    sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
___
    Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
      capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
       chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless disable-gpu --screen-size=1024x640] }
      )

      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
       app,
       browser: :chrome,
       desired_capabilities: capabilities
      )
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.current_driver = :headless_chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- Update chrome            chromedriver-update 2.42
- Check Version              chromedriver -v
- Search Chromedriver              which chromedriver
- Remove chromedriver             rm `which chromedriver`
- Remove Chromedriver and install new one   
  1-   rm chromedriver and Download chromedriver
    2-  unzip chromedriver_mac64\ (2).zip
     3-   echo $APTH (Check your path for executable bin)
     4-  mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin  (Place to the bin)

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions doesn't work, try creating another gemset and execute tests

```
rvm gemset create <your_gemset_name>
rvm gemset use <your_gemset_name>
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Because this issue usually happens whenever there are conflicts between two versions of selenium-webdriver