# Heroku: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515 when using Watir/Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, watir, buildpack

This runs locally (without specifying `driver_path`), but not on Heroku.

**Code:**

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM']
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

I've confirmed below values in heroku rails console

```
ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN'] => "/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome"
ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM'] => "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"
```

**Installed Buildpacks:**

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
```

**Current Error:**

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to
>   chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515

Searching `unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515` on SO returns a bunch of results but none mention heroku.

### Also:

I considered phantomjs. Someone else got it working here,
[Using a headless browser with Heroku Rails Unicorn stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209434/using-a-headless-browser-with-heroku-rails-unicorn-stack)

But its deprecated. Below error when running it locally.

> Selenium support for PhantomJS is deprecated. Use headless
>   Chrome/Firefox or HTMLUnit instead.

### Also Tried:

For transparency, I also tried the following.

Changing `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome`

To `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true`

Though I didn't expect this to work.

### Also Also Tried:

Removing:
`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver`

Adding:
`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome`.

Adding `headless` gem.

And running the below script given in the `watir` gem page, http://watir.com/guides/headless/.

```
require 'watir'
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
b = Watir::Browser.start 'www.google.com'
puts b.title
b.close
headless.destroy
```

**Error:**

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: cannot find
>   Chrome binary

I assume this failed because I didn't specify location of the chrome binary/shim. Couldn't find how to specify this when using `headless` in the docs.

### Tried Per Suggestion:

```
heroku run /usr/bin/chromedriver --app app-name
```

> Running /usr/bin/chromedriver on ⬢ app-name... up, run.2151
>
> (Hobby) bash: /usr/bin/chromedriver: No such file or directory

**Also see below logs that mention `chrome` when deploying to heroku:**

```
remote: -----> chromedriver app detected
remote: -----> Looking up latest chromedriver version...
remote: -----> Downloading chromedriver v2.33...
remote: Archive:  /tmp/chromedriver.zip
remote:   inflating: /tmp/build_cd35072c5b766edaa2b565cbff57e5d6/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver  
remote: -----> Creating chromedriver export scripts...
remote: -----> Google Chrome app detected
...
remote: -----> Fetching https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
...
remote: -----> Creating google-chrome shims
```

### Some Progress:

If I ssh into the heroku server,

`heroku run bash --app app-name`

And search for files with the name `chrome`,

`find /app/ -name "*chrome*"`

```
/app/.profile.d/chromedriver.sh
/app/.profile.d/010_google-chrome.sh
/app/.apt/etc/cron.daily/google-chrome
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome_100_percent.pak
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome_200_percent.pak
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome
/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome
/app/.apt/usr/share/menu/google-chrome.menu
/app/.apt/usr/share/doc/google-chrome-stable
/app/.apt/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
/app/.apt/usr/share/gnome-control-center/default-apps/google-chrome.xml
/app/.apt/usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome.1
/app/.apt/usr/share/appdata/google-chrome.appdata.xml
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.7.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.7.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome.rb
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/browser-2.4.0/test/unit/chrome_test.rb
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/browser-2.4.0/lib/browser/platform/chrome_os.rb
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/browser-2.4.0/lib/browser/chrome.rb
/app/.chromedriver
/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver
```

I can see chromedriver binary at `/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver`.

**So I tried**

`heroku run /app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver --app app-name`

**Result:**

```
Running /app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver on ⬢ app-name... up, run.2067 (Hobby)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

But then running `heroku run rake selenium_namespace:task_one --app app-name` gives the same result.

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to
>   chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515 ...
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:906:in `rescue in
>   block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515
>   (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515)
>   (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) ...

Comment: what is the output from the heroku host when running `heroku run /usr/bin/chromedriver`, this should run the chrome driver manually on your heroku server, maybe some dependencies are not installed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978577/unable-to-connect-to-chromedriver#36439046

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I've updated the question per your suggestion. Does it sound like dependencies are missing?

Comment: We got it up and running, maybe our answer helps you in same way https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781946/135160

Comment: On Ubuntu you would do `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` but I'm not sure how to do it with Heroku

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50729097/5783745) solution worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is possible on Heroku.**

---

#### Confusing `chrome` and `chromedriver`

Your configuration is mixing up **chromedriver** and **Chrome**. `GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM` points to the **Chrome** executable `google-chrome-stable`, not to **chromedriver**. The line below results in Selenium executing the wrong binary, which results in the misleading error message.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM'] # WRONG!
```

As of writing this (Jan '18) the `chromedriver` build pack automatically adds `/app/.chromedriver/bin` to the `$PATH` variable. If you **delete** the above line Selenium should again be able to find `chromedriver` automatically.

#### And then?

You probably added the line above to fix Selenium not being able to find the Chrome binary.  The error message for that would have looked something like:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: cannot find
>   Chrome binary

You can fix this by telling Selenium where the Chrome binary is located using `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options`. The following code should accomplish that.

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
chrome_bin_path = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)
options.binary = chrome_bin_path if chrome_bin_path # only use custom path on heroku
options.add_argument('--headless') # this may be optional
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
driver.navigate.to "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

#### Buildpacks

This should all be possible with the standard `chrome` and `chromedriver` build packs:

`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome.git`
`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git`

You may need `heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome` instead of vanilla `chrome` if you're automating clicks in the browser, but that should *not* be required just to get headless chrome running.

Answer (score 2):

I am quoting [Ilya Vassilevsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367480/ilya-vassilevsky) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258848/run-selenium-with-chrome-driver-on-heroku-cannot-find-chrome-binary#38316296)

> ChromeDriver is just a driver for Chrome. It needs the actual Chrome browser installed on the same machine to actually work.
>
> Heroku doesn't have Chrome installed on its dynos by default. You need to use a buildpack that installs Chrome. For example:
>
> https://github.com/dwayhs/heroku-buildpack-chrome
>
> You can see how it fetches Chrome:
>
> https://github.com/dwayhs/heroku-buildpack-chrome/blob/master/bin/compile#L36-38

Then I read their discussion in the comments:

*Petr Gazarov* says

> I tried this buildpack and it didn't work. I'm suspecting installing google chrome (or any browser) on heroku might be more involved.

*Ilya Vassilevsky* replies

> Yes, Heroku is a very opinionated and closed platform. It should be much easier to set up Chrome with ChromeDriver on your own VM on AWS, Linode, or DigitalOcean.

*Petr Gazarov* replies

> Thanks for your answer Ilya. I ended up re-writing with Watir with phantomjs because I couldn't get Heroku to install Chrome.

You can read more info in that question. 
If something comes to my mind, I will post it.

Comment: Was hoping I wouldn't need a mini-app on digital ocean to do this. But I agree, that might be the only option given the deprecated state of phantomjs.

Comment: I ran into the same problem as OP. Posted a fix as a separate answer. Definitely possible on Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I replaced the line below:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM']
```

for this:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = "/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English site. Can you please answer in English?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this one for more than a few hours ....

It has been very frustrating to try to debug on Heroku CI. This ticket has helped me a lot to find a solution.

I had this piece of code in the spec_helper.rb that was causing trouble (for if it helps someone):

```
config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
  driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
end
```

It was bypassing all the capybara setup...