# Why does firefox open when I run tests instead of the default browser chromium?

Tags: firefox, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, chromium

I have chromium set as my default browser. Every time I run rspec and capybara my firefox browser opens. I prefer to use chrome/chromium for development and personal use, so how do I get chromium to start opening when I run tests?

Answer (score 2):

You should use chrome driver for capybara. Please have a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7512626/582792